# Mockito verify not working with serialized/deserialized mock

Tags: apache-spark, mocking, mockito

I am trying to verify an interaction with a serializable mock that I am using in a spark job. The mock is created with:

```
private val mockFoo = Mockito.mock(classOf[Foo], Mockito.withSettings().serializable())
```

I am then passing this to the constructor of my Spark job class and I am using it like this:

```
rdd.map(elem => foo.doSomethingWith(elem))
```

everything works fine, `doSomethingWith` call is ignored, no interaction with the real object but Spark serializes the mock to send it to a spark worker and deserializes it again in the worker to use it. Even though I'm running the test locally spark is doing all this anyway. This serialization & deserialization means a new instance of the mock is created and that's where the interaction happens so when I'm calling verify on the original mock instance I passed, it fails saying there were no interactions with this mock.

I understand why this is happening and I tested this without spark as well by manually serializing and deserializing a mock.

My question is, is there something I can do to verify the interaction?

Comment: Try broadcasting the mocked object.

Comment: Good catch! That worked, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently broadcasting the mocked object works (example below). Thanks chuckskull :)

In the test:

```
val mockFoo = Mockito.mock(classOf[Foo], Mockito.withSettings().serializable())
val bd = spark.broadcast(mockFoo)
val objUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(bd)
val rdd = objUnderTest.methodUnderTest
// rdd assertions if needed
Mockito.verify(mockFoo).doSomethingWith(elem)
```

Production code:

```
class ClassUnderTest(bd: Broadcast[Foo]) {
  def methodUnderTest(): RDD[Int] = {
    rdd.map(elem => bd.value.doSomethingWith(elem))
  }
}
```